# Внести блок в localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Есть блок:

```
<div class="new-design">
  <p>Перейти на <a href="">новый дизайн</a></p>
  <span class="close-new-design">x</span>
</div>
```

Логика такова, этот блок статично на странице, но его можно закрыть:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close-new-design").on("click", function(){
    $(".new-design").addClass('active');
  });
});
```

При закрытии блока, нужно добавить его в localstorage на 1 час, чтобы после часа блок снова вылез на странице.

Comment: оставь блок в покое, просто добавляй и удаляй ему дисплэй ноне. в сторэдже храни переменную содержащую `new Date()*1`, и проверяй её при обновлении страницы. если её нет или время истекло - покажи свой блок.

Comment: а можешь код написать, я js недавно начал учить) еще не понимаю как что оформить(

Comment: @НикитаФаст settimeout не подойдет потому что после перезагрузки страници, снова будет виден блок, а мне нужно только когда юзер очистить кэш тогда блок будет виден, или же после того как пройдет час и он пропадет из кэша

Comment: @СергійЧуйко на мой взгляд интересная задача ...

Comment: @СергійЧуйко  посмотрите это : https://codepen.io/diproart/pen/bedMKz

Comment: @qwabra можеш код написать как правильно оформить,)? у меня нифига не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего решить эту задачу, используя **куки**, потому что у кук есть время жизни, и проверять нужно лишь то, существует кука или нет.

(*чтобы этот код заработал, нужно нагуглить и скачать плагин jquery.cookie.js*)

```
let cook = $.cookie('cookie_name'); // пытаемся получить куку
if(!cook) { // если куки нет
    $('.new-design').css('display', 'block'); // открываем блок
}
else { // а если кука ещё живая, оставляем блок скрытым
    $('.new-design').css('display', 'none');
}

$(".close-new-design").on("click", function(){ // по клику
    $(".new-design").addClass('active'); // скрываем блок
    $.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', { // ставим куку
        expires: 1/24 // на час
    });
});
```

Можно решить и с помощью **localStorage**, но потребуются дополнительные манипуляции с отсчётом времени, прошедшего с момента клика:

```
let storage = localStorage.getItem('my_storage'); // получаем значение из хранилища
let now = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000); // получаем текущее время в timestamp

if(storage < now) { // если время в хранилище меньше, чем текущее
    $('.new-design').css('display', 'block'); // открываем блок
}
else { // если пока ещё больше (т.е. час не прошёл)
    $('.new-design').css('display', 'none'); // оставляем блок скрытым
}

$(".close-new-design").on("click", function(){ // по клику
    $(".new-design").addClass('active'); // скрываем блок
    localStorage.setItem('my_storage', Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 3600); // записываем в хранилище значение, равное текущему времени + 1 час
});
```

Comment: Подставил ваш код, работает не так как хотелось бы, получается, что при нажатии на закрытие блока, у меня всеравно блок виден, сss стиль display:none; не срабатывает, потому что перебивает его js

Comment: но после того как перезагрузил страницу после нажатия на закрытия блока, то блок уже в localstorage записан, и у него дисплей нон

Comment: @СергійЧуйко, дело не в моём коде, а, скорее всего, вот в этой строчке Вашего кода: $(".new-design").addClass('active'); - по логике должно быть removeClass('active') - то есть по клику он должен скрываться, а у Вас, наоборот, открывается

Comment: @СергійЧуйко  я же тестировал, прежде чем ответ писать - у меня всё работает отлично, оба варианта. так что проблема у Вас